# DB transaction doesn`t work, if i run it as seperate task

Tags: c#, database, transactions, scheduled-tasks

I have this code. Using this code i want to save some entities at background process

```
Task pdfTask = new Task(() =>
                {
                    //some action to create and save entity in DB
                });
                pdfTask.Start();
```

Code to create and save entity

```
var file = new File
            {
                CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Name = createFileDto.Name

            };
            _filesRepository.Add(file);

            UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

but after that action no data in db are created/saved. What i should do to save some entities in DB in the background process? Or what i should change in present code?

Comment: Can you save your file entity in DB successfully without using Task?

Comment: Selim Yıldız yeah, without using Task everything saves succesfully

Comment: So do you get any error? How do you initialize your UnitOfWork?

Comment: Selim Yıldız (_kernel.Get<IUnitOfWork>() as DbContext)?.Initialize(); kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<DbContext>().InRequestScope();